# How to asynchronously call function in parent class component with the right context (this)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I need to call a function in the parent after some async operation in the child. I get an error basically saying "this" is undefined.

Something like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    ......
    openFile (path) {
        ...
        if (someCondition) this.showMessage();
    }
    ......

    ......
    render() {
        <Child openFile={this.openFile}/>
    }
}

function Child ({ openFile }) {
    ......
    const createNewFile = () => {
        // using electron but doubt it matters
        dialog.showOpenDialog(
            // choose file location
        ).then(({path}) => {
            openFile(path)
        })
    }
}
```

The error is "cannot read property 'showMessage' of undefined. Is there a correct way to pass the context in this situation?

Comment: You should just need to [bind openFile in the constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). (I'm assuming when you render `<Child openFile={openFile}>` the prop value is actually `this.openFile`.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond That's it lol. I always wrote it as boilerplate when I was using class components... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, I needed to `.bind(this)` in the parent class component.